# Input fields automatically displays on textarea with add/remove function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need help on removing the items on the textarea when I click the "remove this section", currently it does not remove only the input fields

Secondly is to count how many there are and reflect it to the "Number of children" input field above

Here is My FIDDLE to make it more clear https://jsfiddle.net/sjgrLcqx/12/

Here is the code I am using now

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  var childInfoArray = [];

  var formHtml = '<div class="optionBox"><div class="block added"><input class="crow fullName" type="text" placeholder="Full name"><input class="crow width50 marginsmall age" type="text" placeholder="Age"><input class="crow width50 nomargin gender" type="text" placeholder="gender"><input class="crow interest" type="text" placeholder="Interest"><span class="remove">Remove this section</span></div><div class="block"><span class="add">Add another child\'s info</span></div></div>';

  var formHtml2 = '<div class="block added"><input class="crow fullName" type="text" placeholder="Full name"><input class="crow width50 marginsmall age" type="text" placeholder="Age"><input class="crow width50 nomargin gender" type="text" placeholder="gender"><input class="crow interest" type="text" placeholder="Interest"><span class="remove">Remove this section</span></div>';  

  jQuery('#frmPaymentSantasgrotto').append(formHtml);

  jQuery('.add').click(function () {
    jQuery('.block:last').before(formHtml2);
  });


  jQuery('.optionBox').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    jQuery(this).parent().remove();
  });


  jQuery('.optionBox').on('keyup', 'input', function () {

    var index = $(this).parent().index('div.block');

    var child = {};

    if (childInfoArray[index] != null) {
      child = childInfoArray[index];
    }
    else {
      child = {
        fullName: '',
        age: '',
        gender: '',
        interest: ''
      }
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('fullName')) {
      child.fullName = jQuery(this).val();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('age')) {
      child.age = jQuery(this).val();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('gender')) {
      child.gender = jQuery(this).val();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('interest')) {
      child.interest = jQuery(this).val();
    }
    childInfoArray[index] = child;
    printChildArray();

  });

  function printChildArray() {
    var childInfoString = "";
    childInfoArray.forEach(child => {
      Object.values(child).forEach((attribute, index) => {
        childInfoString += attribute;
        if (index !== Object.keys(child).length - 1) {
          childInfoString += ' | ';
        }
        else {
          childInfoString += ' \n';
        }
      });
    });
    $('textarea').html(childInfoString);
  }

});
```

Here is My FIDDLE to make it more clear https://jsfiddle.net/sjgrLcqx/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete, you are updating the view, but not the array that is used to set the value of the text array control. Your delete should do something like this (pardon my JS. TypeScript and Angular have ruined me):

```
    jQuery('.optionBox').on('click', '.remove', function () {

      // get the index of the item to remove
      var index = $(this).parent().index('div.block');

      // remove it from the array
      childInfoArray.splice(index,1);

      // remove from view
      jQuery(this).parent().remove();

      // call your refresher function to update the textarray
      printChildArray();
    });
```

Also, add a line to update your count in your printChildArray() function:

```
$('#qppquantitySantasgrotto').val(childInfoArray.length);
```

That should fix both of your problems.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have saved my day

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.....

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  var childInfoArray = [];

  var formHtml = '<div class="optionBox"><div class="block" style=""><input class="crow fullName" type="text" placeholder="Full name"><input class="crow width50 marginsmall age" type="text" placeholder="Age"><input class="crow width50 nomargin gender" type="text" placeholder="gender"><input class="crow interest" type="text" placeholder="Interest"><span class="remove">Remove this section</span></div><div class="block"><span class="add">Add another child\'s info</span></div></div>';

  var formHtml2 = '<div class="block" style=""><input class="crow fullName" type="text" placeholder="Full name"><input class="crow width50 marginsmall age" type="text" placeholder="Age"><input class="crow width50 nomargin gender" type="text" placeholder="gender"><input class="crow interest" type="text" placeholder="Interest"><span class="remove">Remove this section</span></div>';  

  jQuery('#frmPaymentSantasgrotto').append(formHtml);

  jQuery('.add').click(function () {
  jQuery('.block:last').before(formHtml2);

});

jQuery(".optionBox").each(function(i) {
   jQuery(this).addClass("list" + ++i);
});

jQuery('.optionBox').on('click', '.remove', function () {
  var index = $(this).parent().index('div.block'); 
  jQuery(this).parent().remove();
  childInfoArray.splice( $.inArray(index, childInfoArray), 1 );
  printChildArray() 
});

jQuery('.optionBox').on('keyup', 'input', function () {

  var index = $(this).parent().index('div.block');

  var child = {};

  if (childInfoArray[index] != null) {
    child = childInfoArray[index];
  }
  else {
    child = {
      fullName: '',
      age: '',
      gender: '',
      interest: ''
    }
  }

  if ($(this).hasClass('fullName')) {
    child.fullName = jQuery(this).val();
  }
  else if ($(this).hasClass('age')) {
   child.age = jQuery(this).val();
  }
  else if ($(this).hasClass('gender')) {
    child.gender = jQuery(this).val();
  }
  else if ($(this).hasClass('interest')) {
    child.interest = jQuery(this).val();
  }
  childInfoArray[index] = child;
  printChildArray();

});

function printChildArray() {
  var childInfoString = "";
  childInfoArray.forEach(child => {
    Object.values(child).forEach((attribute, index) => {
      childInfoString += attribute;
      if (index !== Object.keys(child).length - 1) {
        childInfoString += ' | ';
      }
      else {
        childInfoString += ' \n';
      }
    });
  });
  $('textarea').html(childInfoString);
  $('#qppquantitySantasgrotto').val(childInfoArray.length);
 }

});
```

Comment: now the problem is I cant seem to make this work on multiple forms

Comment: You can't (EVER) have the same 'id' in a page - otherwise, how does JS know what to work with?  You only duplicated your form - which duplicated several ids (frmPaymentSantasgrotto is a prime example) - that can't work.  Give your second form new ids and follow the same logic I showed in the example - it will work.